# What version of LLVM does the latest emscripten use?

Tags: llvm, emscripten, webassembly

What version of LLVM does the latest [emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/) use?
I googled for this quite a while but could not find any info. The background is that I've got some C++ code that requires clang-5.0 - what are the chances that it would compile with emscripten? Or at least code that needs clang-4.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version of emscripten uses clang version 4:

```
$ emcc -v
emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement + linker emulating GNU ld) 1.37.21
clang version 4.0.0 (https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp-clang.git 974b55fd84ca447c4297fc3b00cefb6394571d18) (https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp.git 087c6b7b18b7b769d4ad8f2ac3e0dd0ae6b924c2) (emscripten 1.37.21 : 1.37.21)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

However, you can build WebAssembly without emscripten, by using the clang, llc, s2wasm and wasm tools separately as [documented in this gist](https://gist.github.com/axic/c369b413ae782362f52c6b42bc1e3d7f).

Another good alternative is the wasm-toolchain project:

https://github.com/tpimh/wasm-toolchain

With this installed, I have clang version 6:

```
$ ./clang --version
clang version 6.0.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 9411957410813aeefc1bb299abcb856ce1ef8aae) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 68b21d6108df63d65d6735e9686d53cca844e37a)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Hey that's great, thank you very much! Building without emscripten looks very interesting too. I've considered using _embind_ though, I suppose that would only work if I build using emscripten? So would I be tied to clang-4 or is there any chance of making it work with a newer clang version?

Comment: I honestly have no idea whether you can use embind within emscripten! The tooling is something I am struggling to get my head around.

Comment: You can't use embind without emscripten. The biggest value that emscripten provides (compared to a bare compiler) is the libraries (e.g. libc and libc++, GL, etc) and the JavaScript code that gets packaged with your compiled wasm module. Embind depends on that JS module code.